# How many injective functions are there from {1 2 3} to {4 5 6 7 8)?

Tags: combinatorics

My thoughts are that to find the number of injective functions, just multiply 3 and 5 together since there are 3 elements in the first set and 5 elements in the second. Is this the right way to approach this problem?

Comment: Is there any reason you think this is the right approach to this question? Do the two numbers you multiply play a symmetric role in the problem (as they do in multiplication)?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**  In how many ways can you assign $f(1)$?  Once $f(1)$ has been assigned, in how many ways can you assign $f(2)$?  Once $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ have been assigned, in how many ways can you assign $f(3)$?

Comment: Taussig would it be 3!?

Comment: There are five choices for $f(1)$ since it can be assigned to be any of the five numbers in the set $\{4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$.  Since the function is injective, you now have four choices for $f(2)$.  Once both those choices have been made, you have three choices for $f(3)$. How many injective functions does that yield?

Answer (score 4):

This is called a [Permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) of $n$ things taken $k$ at a time:
$$
P(n,k)=\underbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}_{k\text{ terms}}
$$
This says that there are $n$ ways of placing the first of $k$ items, $n-1$ to place the second, $n-2$ to place the third, and so on, until there are $n-k+1$ ways to place the $k^\text{th}$.

In your case, $n=5$ and $k=3$.

---

As commented by anorton, and mentioned in the link above, $P(n,k)$ is also commonly denoted by the Pochhammer symbol, $(n)_k$, and sometimes by the $k^\text{th}$ falling factorial, $n^{\underline{k}}$.

Comment: As a reference for future viewers, permutations are sometimes denoted with the [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html), $(n)_k$, or the falling power, $n^{\underline{k}}$ (used in Concrete mathematics).

Comment: @anorton: thanks. I have cited your comment above.